# How can I get the value of the data contained in the Asp Dropdown?

Tags: c#, dropdown

There are 4 values in my dropdown list, and if there is an "x" value in it, I want to hide that value. How can I do this using the If command.

```
   protected void dr_alans_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       
            if (dd_mainAlan.SelectedItem.Text == "Yönetici")
            {
                if (dr_alans.Items.FindByValue("22").Value=="22")
                {
                    dr_alans.Items.FindByValue("22").Enabled = false;

                }
                else if (dr_alans.Items.FindByValue("23").Value == "23")
                {
                    dr_alans.Items.FindByValue("23").Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is ASP.NET Forms, you should be able to do it like this maybe. This should hide the items with an x in the Value.

```
foreach (var itm in dd_mainAlan.Items)
{
    var it = (ListItem)itm;
    it.Enabled = !it.Value.Contains("x");
}
```